# Couchbase new field not getting inserted

Tags: c#, .net, couchbase

So initially my class is as follows...

```
public class ClientTransaction
    {
        public decimal ClientBalance { get; set; }
        public DateTime ClientTransactionDate { get; set; }
        public int ClientTransactionTypeId { get; set; }
        public string ClientTransactionTypeName { get; set; }
        public decimal TransactionAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal TaxRate { get; set; }
    }
```

All fields are saved into couchbase.
Then i change the class to add a new field called Description.

```
public class ClientTransaction
    {
        public decimal ClientBalance { get; set; }
        public DateTime ClientTransactionDate { get; set; }
        public int ClientTransactionTypeId { get; set; }
        public string ClientTransactionTypeName { get; set; }
        public decimal TransactionAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal TaxRate { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

I populate the description field and do an upsertAsync but the description field is not in the database even though the upsert was a success.
Please advise.

Comment: Would you mind posting the upsert code that you're using? Also, which version of the Couchbase .NET SDK are you using?